# Header file is not detecting while linking with external library in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am looking into adding the external libraries into CMake. I have the project structure as below

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
|   
├── Demo
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── Demo.cpp
|
├── Hello
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   ├── Hello.cpp
|   └── Hello.h
|   └── lib
|        └── liblibHello.so
```

Demo/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable (helloDemo Demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries (helloDemo Hello)
```

Hello/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Hello SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Hello PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libHello.so)
set_target_properties(Hello PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/)
```

root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (HELLO)
add_subdirectory (Hello)
add_subdirectory (Demo)
```

Initially, it was working if I create a library from the Hello.cpp file. I build the binary once after that I copied the shared library(*liblibHello.so*) into the lib folder.Now its not detecting the header files which I added in the Demo.cpp.

Demo.cpp

```
#include "Hello.h"
int main()
{
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

Hello.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
void print()
{

  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Hello.h

```
void print();
```

I tried to build from build library but I am getting the below error

```
/home/Desktop/Cmake_example/Demo/Demo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Hello.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "Hello.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Demo/CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'Demo/CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/Demo.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Demo/CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/Demo.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'Demo/CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Demo/CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Try `#include <Hello.h>`, with angle-brackets `<>` instead?

Comment: @Some programmer dude : I tried but getting the same error

Comment: By default, IMPORTED library target has **local visibility**: it is visible in `Hello/CMakeLists.txt`, but isn't not visible in `CMakeLists.txt` and in `Demo/CMakeLists.txt` where you call `target_link_libraries`. So, CMake assumes `Hello` is a *plain library name*, and doesn't propagate its properties (`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`) to your executable. See the duplicate question and its answers about the ways how to handle that.

Comment: @tsyvarev Its resolved by adding the GLOBAL in Hello/CMakeLists.txt.```add_library(Hello SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL```